# PHP mysql table rows

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make like following:

I have a page, where users can register..
And another page, with their profile..

mysql table look's like following:

USER

```
-----------------------------------------------
| id | name | age | about | registered | email|
-----------------------------------------------
```

INFO

```
--------------------------------------
| id | title | content | date | hits |
--------------------------------------
```

Informations about user are stored in USER database..

Now user want to add some "INFO" in their accound everyday..

when user add their info, there will be another page wich will show:

**NAME REGISTERED with EMAIL  (from USER database) added following**

TITLE (from INFO database)

CONTENT (from INFO database)

DATE (from INFO database)

HITS (from INFO database)

I really dont know how to do that ..

Pls understand me.. Im newbie on PHP

Cheers!

Comment: You start by learning php and sql then you create what you want. When you have made an effort to do it yourself and if you run into an issue, then you come here to ask for help solving that issue.

Comment: I understand.. i was hope if someone can explain me how to connect that two rows from database in single one

Comment: In that case please edit your question to make it clear what you are asking. At the moment it sounds like you want us to tell you how to write your entire site so it does it all

Comment: I think you're looking for a PHP and mySQL TUTOIRAL site or one where freelance programmers will write all of your code for you. StackOverflow is neither of these.

Comment: Questions describing your requirements and asking someone to write the code for you or explain how to write the code are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please identify a specific problem or question about programming. Include attempted solutions, an explanation of how the results differ from the desired results, and any error messages you receive. Please read the [About](http://www.stackoverflow.com/about) page and [this advice on asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT u.email,i.title,i.content,i.date,i.hits FROM user u,info i where u.id = i.id;
```

Comment: it's look's like what i want// .. i will try that.. ty brother !

Comment: COOL buddy. learn JOINS in SQL

Comment: JOIN .. ok brother.. i will look for tutorials about JOIN,, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the mySQL **JOIN** command that will bring data from two or more data tables together via a specific collaboration.

Comment: i will take in consideration your response.. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't see where you link the `USER table` to the `INFO table`. 
My suggestion is that you must create another table to be able to connect the two tables. Something like:

```
---------------------
| USER_ID | INFO_ID |
---------------------
|    1    |    1    |
---------------------
|    1    |    2    |
---------------------
```

That way, you could make a `JOIN` between the two tables.

Comment: ty for your response.. i will look for JOIN tutorials.. :)